# How to make an array using dummy values from Struct Modal class in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am getting a JSON from my server. To parse the JSON, I am using Decoder and converting the data in my Modal Class object.

This is my Modal class for Decoder:

```
struct SyncModelRecord : Codable {

    var date : String
    var shakeState : Int
}

class SyncModel {

    var date : Date
    var shakeState : Int

    init?(record: SyncModelRecord) {

        guard let secondsFrom1970 = Double(record.date) else {
            return nil
        }

        date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFrom1970)

        shakeState = record.shakeState
    }
}
```

My parsing is working fine.

My problem is that now I have to make a 'SyncModelRecord' dummy array like :

```
var dummySyncModelRecordArray = [SyncModelRecord]()

var syncModelRecord : SyncModelRecord?
syncModelRecord?.shakeState = 0
syncModelRecord?.date = String(Int64(syncTimestamp!))

dummySyncModelRecordArray.append(syncModelRecord!)
```

But this is not working. Its crashing with Error (Please see the below attached error screenshot).

Please advise me.

[image]

Comment: You've never initialized the syncModelRecord, hence the error. This two lines don't complaint syncModelRecord?.shakeState = 0
syncModelRecord?.date = String(Int64(syncTimestamp!)) because you are using conditional unwrap, because syncModelRecord is nil nothing happens swift just ignores those two lines. Also avoid force unwrap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually initialize `syncModelRecord`. Try this:

```swift
let syncModelRecord = SyncModelRecord(date: String(Int64(syncTimestamp!)), shakeState: 0)

dummySyncModelRecordArray.append(syncModelRecord!)
```

Another tip maybe worth exploring, you can directly decode a date and specify the decoder's strategy for it (in your case `secondsSince1970`)

Answer (score 1):

You're *force unwrapping* a value that is nil `syncModelRecord`.

You need to instantiate it when declaring it.

`var syncModelRecord: SyncModelRecord? = SyncModelRecord()`

Or, even better, don't declare it as an optional, since you know at that point that it will not be `nil` (if instantiated correctly, of course):

`var syncModelRecord = SyncModelRecord()`